# Binary relation interface

Tags: java, interface

I'm trying to design a binary relation interface in Java and then implement it, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. I'd really appreciate a little feedback just so I know if I'm way in the wrong direction or not.

This is what I've got so far:

Interface:

```
public boolean compare(Object that, Object ths);
// compares relations to see if they are equal.

public Set<Y> getY(X value);
//return set of all Y values with relation X

public Set<X> getX(Y value);
//return set of all X values with relation Y

public void clear();
//clear relation of values

public Set<Relation<X, Y>> delY(X value);
//remove all relations containing given Y

public Set<Relation<X, Y>> delX(Y value);
//remove all relations containing given X

public String write(Object that);
//output Relation in string format

public Y addPair (X valX, Y valY);
//adds the entry (X, Y) to the Relation

public Y delPair (X valX, Y valY);
//deletes entry (X, Y) from the Relation
```

Implementation:

```
int size;

String[][] basket = new String[16][2];
String[][] bag = basket;



public String addPair(String X, String Y){

    basket[size][0] = X;
    basket[size][1] = Y;

    String pair = basket[size][0] + basket[size][1];
    size++;
    return pair;

}

public boolean compare(String[][] that, String[][] ths){
    that = basket;
    ths = bag;
    boolean equal;

    if(that.equals(ths))
        equal = true;
    else
        equal = false;
    return equal;
}


public Set<String> getY(String X){

    Set<String> Y = new TreeSet<String>();

    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(basket[i][0]==X)
            Y.add(basket[i][1]);
    }

    return Y;

}
public Set<String> getX(String Y){

    Set<String> X = new TreeSet<String>();

    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(basket[i][1]==Y)
            X.add(basket[i][0]);
    }

    return X;

}

public String write(Object o){


    o = basket;
    String out = "";
    out += o.toString();
    System.out.println("OUT: " + out);
    return out;

}



public void clear(){
 for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(basket[i][0]!= null){
            basket[i][0] = null;
            basket[i][1] = null;
        }
    }
}

public Set<String> delY(String X, Relation r){
    Set<String> Y = new TreeSet<String>();

    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(basket[i][0]==X){
            Y.add(basket[i][1]);
            basket[i][1]=null;
        }
    }

    return Y;

}

public Set<String> delX(String Y){
   Set<String> X = new TreeSet<String>();

    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(basket[i][1]==Y){
            X.add(basket[i][1]);
            basket[i][1]=null;
        }
    }


   return X;
}

public String delPair (String X, String Y){
    X = "Orange";
    Y = "Fruit";
    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(basket[i][0]==X && basket[i][1]==Y){
            basket[i][1]=null;
            basket[i][0]=null;
        }
    }

     return (X + Y);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things in here that concern me.... but, the most concerning is:

**Use `.equals()` to compare String values**

Code like this:

> ```
> if(basket[i][0]==X){
> ```

will fail when you get data that is not String-constant data.

That line should be:

```
 if(basket[i][0].equals(X)){
```

This problem is found all over your code.

---

In addition, there are other problems:

- your arrays are pre-sized. This code:

  > ```
  > String[][] basket = new String[16][2];
  > ```

  is potentially OK if you are initializing the array, but what if there are more than 16 pairs?
- it would be better to create a 'Pair' class to contain your two strings, than to use the 2-size array on the `basket`. Then your `basket` could be something like:

  ```
  StringPair[] basket = new StringPair[SIZE];
  ```

  your StringPair class could look something like:

  ```
  public class StringPair {
      private final String first, second;

      public StringPair(String first, String second) {
          this.first = first;
          this.second = second;
      }

      ..... getFirst() .....
      ..... getSecond() .....

  }
  ```
- `compare(String[][] that, String[][] ths)` is a method that needs no state data. It should be a static method, or a utility method. Alternatively, it should be a simple 1-value method `compare(MyClass that)` ... which, for what it is worth, would be very similar to the `equals(...)` method.

  but, that method is pretty broken. It has the two input parameters `that` and `ths`, but it then overwrites those values with the internal versions `bag` and `basket`.

  > ```
  > that = basket;
  > ths = bag;
  > boolean equal;
  >
  > if(that.equals(ths))
  >     equal = true;
  > else
  >     equal = false;
  > return equal;
  > ```

  now, since you set `bag = basket` earlier, this will always return `true`.

  Further, that last 5 lines of the method can be replaced with:

  ```
  return (that.equals(ths));
  ```